# Struts2 addActionError setting result to input automatically on redirect result

Tags: struts2, struts

I have a struts2 action, which sets some error using `addActionError` something like below

```
 public String del() {
        if (new OrdersService().get(idorder) == null) {
            addActionError("Order not found");
        } else {
            new OrdersService().remove(idorder);
            addActionMessage("Order deleted successfully");
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    }
```

So the above method NO MATTER WHAT always return "success" result.

But in struts.xml I've used the redirect result-type to redirect to another action
and that action is never executed instead I'm getting result "input", I'm unable to understand what's going wrong ?

Is it something like
If an action sets an `actionError`, another action can't be executed and straight away "input" result will be thrown. But it doesn't make sense (at least to me)!

[EDIT] including some part of struts.xml

```
<action name="/order/{idorder:[0-9]+}/del" class="actions.OrderAction" method="del">
    <interceptor-ref name="store">
        <param name="operationMode">AUTOMATIC</param>
    </interceptor-ref>
    <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />

    <result name="success" type="redirect">orders</result>
</action>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default stack includes the "workflow" interceptor.

If there are action or field errors this interceptor returns the "input" result, because there was an error.

Reading some documentation will point you in the right direction. Note that your errors will be lost on a redirect anyway, unless you specifically save them.

Also, if you want to redirect to an action, use the "actionRedirect" result type.

Comment: `Note that your errors will be list on a redirect anyway, unless you specifically save them.` - Please explain.

Comment: ok I seem to get it. Docs are awesome, simple & explanatory : http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/workflow-interceptor.html http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/fielderror.html

Comment: I set error in action1 and even if I configure "input" result to be a redirectAction result and hence it should call the second action, but the 2nd action doesn't execute, instead in the browser I see the error saying, 2nd action input result not defined.

Comment: "will be list" was "will be lost", edited. Please note that INPUT result is returned by the workflow interceptor (after validation interceptor raised some input errors) BEFORE the Action is called. If you are getting input, none of the code of the Action will be executed. Note that it would be better to send INPUT result to the same JSP that started the request, for several reasons (you can highlights the wrong fields automatically, preserve all the sent data etc)

Comment: @AndreaLigios just for curiosity - what if I still want to redirect even if I input result. I just saw above and got it!! I'm using `store` interceptor which will refill action errors in the redirected action and hence, I can rectify why in the browser I'm getting 2nd action input result not defined. Thank you guys.

Comment: @XCoder If you're saving error messages, and redirecting, you'll get the input result because you're redirecting to an action and running through the same interceptor.

Comment: Exactly. You should redirecto to an Action under another, very small interceptor stack (no validation, no workflow, etc). Why doing this ? Just send it back, and enjoy that errors are highlighted and fields refilled automatically...

Comment: @AndreaLigios How can I configure INPUT result to return the same JSP that started the request? I'm using validation on the model/bean side.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String del() {
    if (new OrdersService().get(idorder) == null) {
        addActionError("Order not found");
        return ERROR;
    } else {
        new OrdersService().remove(idorder);
        addActionMessage("Order deleted successfully");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

Also include return type 'error' as you have done for return type 'success' in your action mapping in struts.xml