# Struts 2.3 Store Interceptor : How to pass ActionErrors from Interceptor to Action?

Tags: java, struts2, interceptor, struts2-interceptors

I have been reading about the `StoreInterceptor` in the Struts 2 docs, and it talks about how to stick the StoreInterceptor in your Action definition in your `struts-config.xml`, and it just works. But that is if you are creating and adding the `ActionErrors` from within the Action.

My problem is that I am doing a Login using a `LoginInterceptor` which, if the Login fails, adds an `ActionError` like so:

```
((ActionSupport) invocation.getAction()).addActionError("Login failed");
```

It's added just fine, but when I get to the LoginAction, which is invoked *after* the `LoginInterceptor`, `ValidationAwareSupport.actionErrors` is `null`.

I thought that by adding the `StoreInterceptor` like this, it would store the `ActionErrors`, either in request or session (using the `operationMode` `"store"` or `"retreive"` parameter):

```
<action name="login" class="...LoginFormAction" >
 <interceptor-ref name="store">
  <param name="operationMode">store</param>
 </interceptor-ref>
 <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
  <result name="input" type="tiles">adminLogin</result>
  <result name="success" type="tiles">adminLogin</result>
</action>
```

But it's not working. I've also tried adding the `StoreInterceptor` directly to the defaultStack, that doesn't work either.

Does `StoreInterceptor` work not just for saving `ActionErrors` between Actions, but also between Interceptors and Actions?

Comment: What are you trying to do? What kind of errors are you trying to store?

Comment: Simple Login stuff. If a user (ie. entered username and password) isn't found in the database, We upgraded from 2.1 to 2.3.16 and this broke. Up until now we were doing this: if (userDoesNotExist) { ((ActionSupport) invocation.getAction()).addActionError("Login failed"); } and this ActionError was automatically available in the Action that was executed immediately after the LoginInterceptor. But not anymore. When I get to the LoginAction, validationAware.actionErrors is null.

Comment: Hmm. It should work fine if you're in the same HTTP request. Why not perform this kind of validation in the LoginAction, though?

Comment: Good question. Legacy code. I can't change it. In the end since this Interceptor is only being called before LoginFormAction, if there's an error I temporarily stick in the the Session Map, recover it in LoginFormAction, and then manually add the errors to LoginFormAction's actionErrors. It's a kludge, and the better fix would be to just implement it in LoginFormAction directly but, we're pressed for time. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Try my solution to a similar problem posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15497158/action-message-and-action-error-is-not-forwarding-to-the-different-action-in-str/22045236#22045236

Answer (score 0):

The [`store` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/scope-interceptor.html) works between two actions, one of them store the messages, another retrieve them.

In you configuration you have only one action. The second action should be configured to retrieve messages.

The [`store` interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/core-developers/scope-interceptor.html) doesn't work between action and interceptor or between interceptors.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. Any idea in what version of Struts this behavior (not being able to propagate ActionErrors created in an Interceptor to an Action) was changed? I can't seem to get it to work. I've been playing with the "new" ValidationErrorAware interface, but all that seems to do is allow you to implement a actionErrorOccurred() method, so that from within your Interceptor you can change the result name. That doesn't help me.

Comment: Is `LoginAction` the same as `LoginFormAction`? If not why didn't you configure it to ref `store` interceptor in `retrieve` mode? There's also no need to use the second action, just return a `dispatcher` type result.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's LoginFormAction, not LoginAction. But the work is (unfortunately) done in the LoginInterceptor and the errors need to be passed from the LoginInterceptor to LoginFormAction. I tried using StoreInterceptor both with "store" and "retrieve" but neither worked. If what you say is true, that it won't work from Interceptor to Action, then it's normal. But I'm not sure what you mean when you say "just return a dispatcher type result". Where, in the Interceptor? I've more or less solved it by sticking messages in Session temporarily, see my comment above. Not perfect but ...

Comment: If you don't have two different actions (methods) then you don't need the `store` interceptor. You don't have the action errors because either you have another request via redirect to login action, or using a different thread (rare case). You shouldn't return `dispatcher` result to the location mapped as action, but should be path to JSP. I don't know your workflow, nor configuration, I don't know why do you need login action, but you could try to return `chain` global result to action from your interceptor. It should be global, because you don't have any other place to configure it.

Comment: No, I don't have 2 different Actions but I do have an Interceptor, followed by an Action. Totally unnecessary, as I said above, but it's legacy, I can't change it. For the time I've more or less solved it by sticking messages in Session temporarily. Not an elegant solution. I would love to get rid of the Interceptor altogether, it's useless. Heck, I'd love to get rid of struts, plug in Spring, and use Spring Security. But for the time being ... Anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Spring and Spring Security both are integrated with Struts2, the MVC framework is a choice. Yeah, I see you just didn't get it.

Comment: Yes, I know Spring can be integrated with Struts. In fact we use it to inject our domain beans in our Actions. I also knew that Spring Security could be integrated in Struts. But unfortunately I can't just plug in Spring Security because references to the legacy, ad-hoc security system are everywhere in the app -- in the Actions and jsps there are references to Session, etc. It's pretty bad, and it would take a lot of work to remove it. And right now we don't have the time (or permission) to change it. But it's on the wish list, as is moving to Spring MVC, which I like better. One day ...

Comment: What is bad or what is good doesn't relate to your question, does it?

Comment: Um .. Just saying our current security system is poorly implemented, which is also why it would be difficult to remove, so I can't get rid of it yet. Otherwise I'd love to plug in Spring Security.

Comment: What a security system?